# How to make Oracle procedure return result sets

Tags: plsql

SQL Server procedure can return result sets. I have a table **emp(emp__id, emp__name, ...)**. The procedure below will return a list of employees that matched with the name provided.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_employee_by_name ( @name VARCHAR(100) )
AS
SELECT emp_id, emp_name
FROM emp
WHERE emp_name = @name;
```

So in the client code, to get the data I use ADO.NET.

```
SQLDataAdapter adapter = new SQLDataAdapter("get_employee_by_name", cnString);
SQLDataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
DataTable dt = new DataTable("employee");

adapter.Fill(dt);
```

How can I code equivalently in PL/SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a Ref cursor for the Stored Procedure:
http://www.oradev.com/ref_cursor.jsp

For the client part use the Oracle Data Provider. You can download it from Oracle and the syntax is similar to the SQLDataAdapter. Something like this:

```
OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter();
da.SelectCommand = new OracleCommand("get_employee_by_name", Connection);
OracleParameter prm = da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("pName", OracleDbType.VarChar2);
prm.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
prm.Value = "MyName";
prm = da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("pResult", OracleDbType.RefCursor);
prm.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
```