# Basic Oracle question

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, ora-00904

I am new to oracle.  When I create a stored procedure using:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROCEDURE1 
AS
BEGIN

  SELECT FIRSTNAME,
         LASTNAME
    INTO FirstName,LastName
    FROM EMPLOYEE;

END PROCEDURE1;
```

i get the following errors:

> PL/SQL Statement Ignored
>    Identifier FIRSTNAME must be declared
>    ORA-00904 Invalid identifier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the "AS" keyword won't work. If it doesn't work, then use "IS".
Rest are fine and very good tips.

If you need any help regarding PL/SQL, then you can have a look at this link. It is very simple and easy to understand;
http://plsql-tutorial.com/

This is my solution to the error which you are getting;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROCEDURE1 IS
  v_FIRSTNAME EMPLOYEE.FIRSTNAME%TYPE;
  v_LASTNAME EMPLOYEE.LASTNAME%TYPE;
  CURSOR EMPCURSOR IS
  SELECT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME FROM EMPLOYEE;      
  BEGIN   
     IF NOT EMPCURSOR%ISOPEN THEN
         OPEN EMPCURSOR;
     END IF;
     LOOP
        FETCH EMPCURSOR INTO V_FIRSTNAME,V_LASTNAME;
        EXIT WHEN EMPCURSOR%NOTFOUND;
     END LOOP;
     IF EMPCURSOR%ISOPEN THEN
        CLOSE EMPCURSOR;
     END;
  END PROCEDURE1;
```

You can also use `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_FIRSTNAME || ','|| V_LASTNAME)`, inside the loop to display the output. but in order to do that, you first need to execute the command `server output on`

Comment: I'm adding my comment here for the previous question.....
into statement works only if there is a single record or if you are trying to fetch a single record.
You need to you cursors to loop through the records.

Comment: Actually, you can populate a `%ROWTYPE` variable, which provides similar to %TYPE -- don't have to worry about data type changes, besides row variable shorthand...

Comment: in a PL/SQL PROCEDURE (or FUNCTION) declaration, AS and IS are synonymous and either one may be used.

Answer (score 7):

You need to declare variables before you attempt to populate them:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROCEDURE1 
AS

 FirstName EMPLOYEE.FIRSTNAME%TYPE;
 LastName EMPLOYEE.LASTNAME%TYPE;

BEGIN

  SELECT FIRSTNAME,
         LASTNAME
    INTO FirstName,LastName
    FROM EMPLOYEE;

END PROCEDURE1;
```

The %TYPE notation is shorthand for data type declaration that matches the column data type.  If that data type ever changes, you don't need to update the procedure.

Comment: It is also a good idea to not name your variables the same as the columns.

Answer (score 3):

You need to declare the variables.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE PROCEDURE1 AS
 V_FIRSTNAME VARCHAR2(60);
 V_LASTNAME  VARCHAR2(60);
BEGIN
        SELECT FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME
         INTO V_FIRSTNAME ,V_LASTNAME  
         FROM EMPLOYEE;
END PROCEDURE1;
```

---

In reply to your comment, SQL statements in PL/SQL block can fetch only 1 record. If you need to fetch multiple records, you will need to store the records in a cursor and process them.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
    PROCEDURE PROCEDURE1 AS

     CURSOR EMP_CUR IS
         SELECT FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME
         FROM EMPLOYEE;
    EMP_CUR_REC EMP_CUR%ROWTYPE;

    BEGIN
     FOR EMP_CUR_REC IN EMP_CUR LOOP
         -- do your processing
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Employee first name is ' || EMP_CUR_REC.FIRSTNAME);
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Employee last name is ' || EMP_CUR_REC.LASTNAME);
    END LOOP;
    END PROCEDURE1;
```

To explain: 
   `EMP_CUR` holds the SQL statement to be executed.
   `EMP_CUR_REC` holds the records that will be fetched by the SQL statement.
    `%ROWTYPE` indicates that the Record will be of the same data type as the row which holds the data

The `FOR LOOP` will fetch each record, and you can do whatever processing that needs to be done.

Comment: Can i have something like Select * from Tablename or select firstname,lastname from tablename  , like we have in sql server

Comment: No, that's not possible in a PL/SQL block.

Comment: Now i get this error,      <br> ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows<br>
ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.PROCEDURE1", line 5<br>
ORA-06512: at line 2<bR>

Comment: In PL/SQL you can fetch only 1 record - it cannot be zero or it cannot be more than one. Can you explain what exactly you're trying to do ?

Comment: @sathya : by the above way can i read the result from .Net code

Comment: Not sure, I think you will have to return it as a ref cursor. Ref this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304600/how-to-make-oracle-procedure-return-result-sets

Answer (score 1):

In a response to @Sathya's answer above @kayak asked "Can i have something like Select * from Tablename or select firstname,lastname from tablename , like we have in sql server".

Yes, you can do that, but you'll either need to include a WHERE clause or use a cursor.  If you include a WHERE clause which limits your results to a single row you could write something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROCEDURE1
IS
  rowEmployees EMPLOYEE%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT *
    INTO rowEmployees
    FROM EMPLOYEE
    WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = 12345;
END PROCEDURE1;
```

On the other hand, if you either don't have a WHERE clause because you wish to process all rows in the table, or you have a WHERE clause which doesn't limit your results to a single row you could use a cursor in the following manner:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROCEDURE1 IS
BEGIN
  FOR rowEmployees IN (SELECT *
                         FROM EMPLOYEE
                         WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID IN (12345, 67890, 111213, 141516))
  LOOP
    <do something with rowEmployees here>
  END LOOP;
END PROCEDURE1;
```

Share and enjoy.